# Como evitar redireccionamiento de pagina en un alert con Javascript y jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuando muestro un alert de JS me redirecciona al inicio de mi pagina y se pierde toda la información de un formulario y lo que quiero es que muestre el alert  pero que no redireccione ni recargue ¿Como puedo evitar el redireccionamiento, despues de aceptar el alert?, el alert es el comun, por lo que no he agregado ningun parametro

```
    $("#btnagregarSIM").click(function() {

      var cantidadTotalSim = $("#txtValorTotalSim").val();
      var cantidadArticulo = $("#txtValorTotalArticulo").val();
      var facturaSim = $("#txtFacturaSIM").val();
      var cantidadSim = $("#txtCantidadsim").val();
      var idSim = $("#cmbSim").val();
      var descripcionSim = $("#cmbSim option:selected").html();

      var x = parseFloat(cantidadTotalSim) + parseFloat(cantidadSim);

      if (x <= cantidadArticulo) {
        if (cantidadTotalSim <= cantidadArticulo) {
          fn_agregarSIM(facturaSim, cantidadSim, idSim, descripcionSim);
        } else {
          alert("Revisa que la cantidad de SIM sea la misma que la cantidad de Articulos")
        }
      } else {
        alert("La cantidad de SIM no puede ser mayor que la cantidad total de articulos.");
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un alert no debería redirigirte, lo que puede pasar es que el botón "#btnagregarSIM" sea un submit y este ejecute automáticamente el envío del formulario asociado.

para lo cual deberías agregar la llamada a preventDefault en la función click de la siguiente forma

```
 $("#btnagregarSIM").click(function(event) {

    ...

    if (x <= cantidadArticulo) {
        if (cantidadTotalSim <= cantidadArticulo) {
            fn_agregarSIM(facturaSim, cantidadSim, idSim, descripcionSim);

        } else { 
            alert("Revisa que la cantidad de SIM sea la misma que la cantidad de Articulos");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    } else { 
        alert("La cantidad de SIM no puede ser mayor que la cantidad total de articulos.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ubicandolo ahí afecta también el camino feliz del formulario, me parece que debería ir después de ambos alert.

Comment: Gracias, por la observación, corregido.

Comment: Era eso o tratar de robarte la respuesta.. ;) saludos!

Comment: Gracias! saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Debes checar que el botón #btnagregarSIM no sea un tipo submit. En tal caso hay que quitar la etiqueta "form" o solo cambiar el botón por una etiqueta "a".

Comment: el boton lo tengo como <button></button> esta mal?

Comment: trata de cambiarlo a <a href='#'>...</a> y te puede funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación de Jquery debes usar el método preventDefault para evitar que el evento llame siga su comportamiento normal.

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
```